# Inherit widget values in CQ/AEM?

Tags: inheritance, widget, aem, xtype

Is there an easy way to inherit a page property that was set using a widget to the subpages?

For now, the only way I see is, to create a custom xtype and use a servlet (for reading the value) to get this working.

Thank you for suggestions,
Benedikt

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about anything at client-side. But for server-side there is [InheritanceValueMap](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/inherit/InheritanceValueMap.html).